# DELETE Trigger Not working - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, events, triggers

First table - rm_desc
Second table - room_cat_mapping

Want to achieve : while deleting record from rm_desc automatically it should delete related record from  room_cat_mapping as well.

BUT BELOW TRIGGER IS NOT WORKING, ANY clue new to trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS DELETE_ROOM_TYPES;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    TRIGGER `DELETE_ROOM_TYPES` BEFORE DELETE
    ON `rm_desc`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM room_cat_mapping
        WHERE room_cat_mapping.prop_id = rm_desc.res AND room_cat_mapping.room_cat_id = rm_desc.rm_cat;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why do you use a trigger and not foreign keys with cascaded delete? What error message do you get?

Comment: You should make clear what's not working. Error? Nothing happens?

Comment: @shadow - not foreign keys with cascaded delete because  room_cat_mapping same records can repeat as well

Comment: @andy -' not working' means while deleting record from rm_desc automatically it's not deleting related record from room_cat_mapping as well

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS DELETE_ROOM_TYPES;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE

    TRIGGER `DELETE_ROOM_TYPES` AFTER DELETE
    ON `rm_desc`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM room_cat_mapping
        WHERE room_cat_mapping.prop_id = OLD.res AND room_cat_mapping.room_cat_id = OLD.rm_cat;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I changed the trigger to **AFTER** and referenced the deleted row values using **OLD**.

Comment: SORRY no it's not working, is there foreign key CONSTRAINT need to add for room_cat_mapping. currently? currently there is no relation between these two table, is that a issue? because i tried before also it was not working